# Create a Driver helper to access the user's Google Drive

Tags: google-app-engine, google-drive-api

I export the files which are in my server account Drive to my google user's Drive, and now I want to give them new names.
The code I used is in the following, but it returns 'Invalid Credentials'

```
user_credentials = oauth2client.contrib.appengine.StorageByKeyName(
      oauth2client.contrib.appengine.CredentialsModel,
      user_id, 'credentials').get()
self.service = googleapiclient.discovery.build('drive', 'v2', credentials=user_credentials)
```

I have googled this question, but I haven't found answers that I wanted.

Comment: the user_id is my google account

Comment: Were you able to check if you are obtaining and, where necessary, refreshing the access token?

Comment: The credentials it returned were None, I want to use my google drive through my google account  instead of the project's service account. I followed the step with Storage in [link](https://developers.google.com/api-client-library/python/guide/google_app_engine). But it didn't work.